# JS/jQuery switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know your opinion about my simple JS/jQquery switcher. Is it a good idea to use `toggle()`?

```
var s = $('.slider'), i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    var o = $([]);
        o = o.add(s[i]);
    if(i === s.length - 1) {
        i = -1;
    }
    i++;
    o = o.add(s[i]);

    o.toggle();
}, 1000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skowron_line/ch4g8/1/)

Comment: Why are you saving the options in the DOM and not in a JavaScript array? http://jsfiddle.net/D37qR/

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise you to modularize your code to make it testable an reusable.

Since you are using jQuery, you could use the [widget factory](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/).

I have created an example for you, perhaps it will look overkill and it might be, however it's just an example. Also, I strongly advise you to read how to write [testable javascript](http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript).

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider"></div>

<input id="items-input" type="text" value="abcdef">

<button id="state-btn">Stop</button>
```

**WIDGET**

```
!function ($) {
    $.widget('mylib.layerSlider', {
        options: {
            interval: 1000,
            autoSlide: true,            
            createItemUI: function (item) {
                return $('<div>').html(item);
            }
        },

        _create: function () {
            this.element.addClass('mylib-layer-slider');
            this._layout();
            this.options.autoSlide && this.startSliding();
        },

        _setOptions: function (options) {
            this._super(options);
            this._layout();
        },

        _layout: function () {

            var wasSliding = this.isSliding(),
                createItemUI = this.options.createItemUI,
                $items = this._$items = $($.map(this.options.items, function (item) {
                    return createItemUI(item).addClass('item').get();
                }));

            this.stopSliding();

            this.element.empty().append($items);

            this._index = 0;

            wasSliding && this.startSliding();
        },

        _showNext: function () {
            var i = this._index,
                $items = this._$items;

            $items.eq(i).hide();
            $items.eq(this._index = ++i % $items.length).show();
        },

        _destroy: function () {
            this.stopSliding();
            this.element.removeClass('mylib-layer-slider').empty();
        },

        startSliding: function () {
            if (this.slideTimerId) return;

            this.slideTimerId = setInterval($.proxy(this._showNext, this), this.options.interval);
        },

        stopSliding: function () {
            clearInterval(this.slideTimerId);
            this.slideTimerId = null;
        },

        isSliding: function () {
            return !!this.slideTimerId;
        }
    });
}(jQuery);
```

**DOM READY**

```
$(function ($) {
    var operations = ['Start', 'Stop'],
        $itemsInput = $('#items-input').keyup(function () {
            $slider.layerSlider('option', 'items', $itemsInput.val().split(''));
        }),
        $slider = $('#slider').layerSlider({
            items: $itemsInput.val().split('')
        });

    $('#state-btn').click(function (e) {
        var i = +$slider.layerSlider('isSliding');

        $slider.layerSlider(operations[i].toLowerCase() + 'Sliding');

        $(this).text(operations[++i % 2]);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ch4g8/3/)